# Get all bindings from $sql

Tags: php, pdo, preg-match

I'd like to get all bindings from my sql statement. The statement looks like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (f_name, l_name) values (:f_name, :l_name)";
```

The Output should be `:f_name, :l_name`
How an I achive this? Preg match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be various ways to do this, this uses `preg_match_all()` and a regex of `:(\w*)\b` (basically a `:` followed by characters up to a word boundary)...

```
preg_match_all("/:(\w*)\b/", $sql, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

which gives you

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => :f_name
            [1] => :l_name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => f_name
            [1] => l_name
        )

)
```